# Set KMS server from Windows S Mode

Tags: windows, windows-activation

I did a fresh install of Windows Enterprise N

To get out of Windows S mode I need to activate Windows

I can't run the batch script from IT, or slmgr.vbs, which means I can't change the KMS server to our KMS server.

Is there some GUI, non-blocked way to set the KMS server from Windows S mode and perform the verification?

Comment: What does your IT Administrator say about the matter?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment to provide this necessary.